# Не понимаю принцип работы оператора continue в бесконечном цикле

Tags: java, for, continue

Есть код:

```
for (int i=0; ;i++){
  if (i>3){
    continue; // переход к следующей итерации, не завершая предыдущую
  }
  System.out.println("ddd");
}
```

В случае, когда цикл не бесконечный, программа выводит ddd в консоль 4 раза и больше ничего не выводит. В бесконечном же цикле, она также выводит ddd 4 раза, останавливается на секунду, после чего начинает бесконечно выводить ddd в консоль. 
Почему это происходит?

Comment: А-а-а, я догaдался. Происходит переполнение счетчика.

Comment: @Igor тогда не бесконечно, а опять до 3. Но это происходит долго, поэтому кажется, что бесконечно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В бесконечном цикле:

> она также выводит ddd 4 раза

Это понятно - `i` от нуля до трех.

> останавливается на секунду

`i` от четырех до максимального целого

> начинает бесконечно выводить ddd

`i` от минимального целого (минус два миллиарда) до трех

Кажется, что это бесконечно, так как вывод в консоль двух миллирадов строк занимает очень много времени.

Comment: То есть получается цикл идёт по кругу?

Comment: @НиколайСеменов Da.

Comment: @Drakonoved Da.

Comment: Премного благодарен!